# HTML / Javascript display images from user input checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html

I am relatively familiar with HTML but am having a hard time with some of the Javascript side of things. Below is some code where the user inputs a year, month, day, and hour and an image is produced:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  var yyyy = document.getElementById('YYYY').value
  var mm = document.getElementById('MM').value
  var dd = document.getElementById('DD').value
  var hh = document.getElementById('HH').value
  url_wpc_sfc = "https://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/archives/sfc/" + yyyy + "/namussfc" + yyyy + mm + dd + hh + ".gif"
  url_wpc_fronts = "https://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/archives/sfc/" + yyyy + "/usfntsfc" + yyyy + mm + dd + hh + ".gif"
  url_wpc_bw = "https://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/archives/sfc/" + yyyy + "/print_us" + yyyy + mm + dd + hh + ".gif"
  img = document.createElement('img')
  img.src = url_wpc_sfc
  document.body.appendChild(img)
  img.src = url_wpc_fronts
  document.body.appendChild(img)
  img.src = url_wpc_bw
  document.body.appendChild(img)
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="YYYY" value="Enter year (YYYY)"> <br>
  <input type="text" id="MM" value="Enter month (MM)"> <br>
  <input type="text" id="DD" value="Enter day (DD)"> <br>
  <input type="text" id="HH" value="Enter hour (HH)"> <br>
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Get Data">
</form>
```

The problem I am having is two-fold:

1. How do I make it so all 3 images are appended to one another? When I run the above code, only the most recent image via the defined url is produced (url_wpc_bw).
2. The end goal is to have n number of checkboxes for the n number of possible url / image combinations. For this scenario, n = 3. For example, The user would be able to select a checkbox with 'wpc_sfc' and then the image based on their input will be produced. Furthermore, if they select a checkbox with 'wpc_sfc' as well as 'wpc_bw', two images would be produced based on their input for the year, month, day, and hour.

Comment: If you're trying to display three images, you will need to make three new `img` elements. Right now, you are overriding the `src` property of the original `img` tag you created which is why only the last source you set is visible.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  var yyyy = document.getElementById('YYYY').value
  var mm = document.getElementById('MM').value
  var dd = document.getElementById('DD').value
  var hh = document.getElementById('HH').value
  url_wpc_sfc = "https://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/archives/sfc/" + yyyy + "/namussfc" + yyyy + mm + dd + hh + ".gif"
  url_wpc_fronts = "https://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/archives/sfc/" + yyyy + "/usfntsfc" + yyyy + mm + dd + hh + ".gif"
  url_wpc_bw = "https://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/archives/sfc/" + yyyy + "/print_us" + yyyy + mm + dd + hh + ".gif"

  let img = document.getElementById('setimg');
  let htm = '';
  htm = `
        <img src="url_wpc_sfc">
        <img src="url_wpc_fronts">
        <img src="url_wpc_bw">
        `;
  img.outerHTML = htm;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="YYYY" value="Enter year (YYYY)"> <br>
  <input type="text" id="MM" value="Enter month (MM)"> <br>
  <input type="text" id="DD" value="Enter day (DD)"> <br>
  <input type="text" id="HH" value="Enter hour (HH)"> <br>
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Get Data">
</form>
<div id="setimg"></div>
```

maybe like this?